# The definition of equality of sets and functions are contradictory.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, relations

Suppose we have two functions $f=\{(1,2),(3,4)\}$ and $g=\{(1,2),(3,4)\}$ with codomains $A$ and $B$ respectively so that $A\not=B.$ Then since $f$ and $g$ are sets, then the definition of equality of sets as defined [here](https://www.cs.odu.edu/%7Etoida/nerzic/content/set/basics.html#:%7E:text=Definition%20(Equality%20of%20sets)%3A,%5B%20x%20A%20x%20B%20%5D%20.) implies that the two sets-functions-are equal. But following the defination of equality of functions as defined [here](https://mathstats.uncg.edu/sites/pauli/112/HTML/secfuneq.html#:%7E:text=7.2%20Equality%20of%20Functions&text=Two%20functions%20are%20equal%20if,all%20elements%20of%20the%20domain.) the two functions-sets-are not equal. Contradiction. Both definitions are contrdictiary! Have I done some mistake? Thanks.

Comment: @Joe So mathematicians define terms differently according to their needs and mood? This is not mentioned in my math book.

Comment: In short, yes. Definitions are not universal truths etched into stone; they are simply convenient *abbreviations*. For example, saying that a set $S$ is "countable" is an abbreviation of saying that there is a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $S$. But wait ... some authors use countable to mean there is a bijection between a subset of $\mathbb N$ and $S$. That might be a more useful convention in a certain context.

Comment: @Joe so what definition of equality of sets is used by the people who use the equality of function mentioned in the question?

Comment: A set is not a function until a mapping is established. It can also be undefined for some (or even all) elements. Concerning Joe's comment : Finite sets are also countable , but usually the set is already infinite if we ask whether it is countable, and then the issue vanishes.

Comment: @Osmium: Everyone agrees that two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal if and only if $$(\forall x)(x\in A \iff x\in B) \, .$$This is in fact an [axiom of ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory). However, some authors define a function as a set of ordered pairs blah blah blah... (like you did in your question), whereas others would call the aforementioned set the *graph* of a function—the actual function consists of a domain, codomain, and the graph. It is only in the second approach where the concept of a "codomain" really makes any sense.

Comment: @Osmium: For instance, according to the first definition, the following functions are identical, since they are the same set:$$
f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R, f(x)=x^2 \quad g:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty),g(x)=x^2
$$Therefore, it makes no sense to call $g$ surjective and $f$ non-surjective. But according to the second defintion, $f$ and $g$ are different functions as they have different codomains.

Comment: @Osmium: Finally, it's worth noting that while it is true that functions are sets in the context of set theory, there's no point in getting too hung up on the precise set-theoretic formulation of a mathematical concept. For example, in set theory, *numbers* like $\sqrt{2}$ and $\pi$ are also sets, but a statement such as $\sqrt{2}\subset\pi$ would make little sense to the working mathematician (even if such a statement would technically be true in the set-theoretic abstraction of the theory).

Comment: @Peter: It is fairly common to define a countable set as a set with exactly the same cardinality as the natural numbers (so finite sets are not considered countable). See, for instance, Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (chapter 2) or Terence Tao's *Analysis I* (chapter 8). In this usage, a set with a cardinality that is less than or equal to $\mathbb N$ is called *at most countable*.